# Is it Possible to connect netbeans with Firebase?

Tags: java, android, mysql, firebase

We are creating a desktop application in java netbeans with database as mysql and a android application with database as Firebase. Need to connect firebase realtime database with java and using net beans sdk is this possible ? If possible Please Explain how?

Comment: Do you want to connect your IDE (netbeans) to firebase or the desktop application you are creating?

Comment: desktop application to firebase

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions not for software related questions about finding a tutorial or pluging to connect netbeans to firebase there for i vote closing this question. This question should be asked on super user https://superuser.com/.

Comment: @PratikRathi You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49364641/edit) your question saying you want to connect your desktop application and not netbeans itself. Also include the language this application is written in.

Comment: @RaymondNijland This question isnt about connecting netbeans but an application written in netbeans. So its not software related just poorly phrased.

Comment: yeah you said it right.. I couldn't explained it correctly but you got it right @AndréKool

Comment: Need to connect firebase realtime database with java and using net beans sdk for develop desktop app

Comment: Why down voting for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Admin SDK that allows accessing Firebase Database from regular JVM applications [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start). Note however that this Admin SDK gives full administrative access to the users of the JVM app, so it is typically only meant to be used in administrative applications.

If that is not what you want, you can consider accessing the Firebase Database through its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start). While this is definitely more work than using the Android or Admin SDKs, it is available to developers from *any* platform that can make HTTP calls including Java desktop apps.